# FlexUnit 4 and Cairngorm commands

Tags: flex3, flexunit, flexunit4

Does anyone know if it is possible to test remote procedure calls in Cairngorm Commands with FlexUnit 4. I have an old app full of them and before I introduce FlexUnit into the mix would like to hear if anyone has been successful with this.

Many thanks,

Comment: Found it. http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Writing_an_AsyncTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy using asynchronous tests (as you've found the relevant doc) - as long as you can exchange the remote service with a mock service, e.g. by injecting a different service locator that returns mock services, or better by using a DI framework like Spring ActionScript or Parsley. In that case you will have a real unit test that is not depending on a running server.